# how do I align this text box in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move this textbox down but ever time I try to positon it, it over laps my slideshow. Is there something that needs to be changed in my css so that it wont overlap and take my vertical scrollbar away?

```
<section id="main_section">
        <article>
        <header>
             <hgroup>
                <center><h1>What is Iamdrivingtoday.com?</h1></center>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
            <p>Iamdrivingtoday.com is where we specialize in providing auto loans for people with bad credit. 
            We know that new and used car customers in certain times need help
            finding the right auto loan provider. If you think you 
            have a really bad, or low credit rating, or you have been
            turned down in the past, chances are we can help!  
            Our specialty is getting you financed and we guarantee an
            approval!</p>
        </article>
        <article>
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                <center><h1>Having a hard time getting approved?</h1></center>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
            <p>No matter what your prior credit which may be due to bankruptcy, divorce, 
            foreclosure, repossession, late payments, or unpaid balances we get
            you driving the same day no matter your circumstances.
            Just fill out the application and drive away today.</p>
        </article> 
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
#main_section{

    border:1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
     2px 2px 0 #000,  
      1px 1px 0 #000;

    background-image:url('tb.png');
    background-size: 365px 275px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 625px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qdyk/)**

Comment: Can you provide an example to illustrate what is happening?

Comment: Honestly your explanation doesn't say much, but putting your code into a JSFiddle, I found that margin-right is really squeezing your content to the left. I removed it. Look at the result here http://jsfiddle.net/yf3yp/

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2zfsktk/8

its doing this but i dont want it to look so wide.

Comment: all i want is to move it down..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#main_section{

border:1px solid black;
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
background-image:url('tb.png');
background-size: 365px 275px;
background-color:#ccc;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
margin: 50px 65px 0px 50px;
padding: 20px 20px;
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
```

}